# Is there any way to implement user area in abp solution

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have a little problem about this scenario.
I have 300 users in my system. each user must have user panel. it is one page that each user after sign in to the system and went to own page,can edit his content and customize it.
my question is : how to define permission for each user in order to access to own page and don't access to other's personal page.

thank you.

Comment: You don't need a permission if every user can access this page. Instead, load the personal page using `AbpSession.UserId` instead of a user-supplied ID.

Answer (score 0):

You just need [AbpAuthorize] attribute for the related application service to prevent unauthorized users to see that personal page. And when the user opens the page load the data with the current user's information as @aaron stated in the comments.